# Navigate to nested route with React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a problem routing to a nested navigator from different stacks. My React Native app is setup with routes in the following structure using React Navigation 5.x

- Home
- Post Home

  - Post
- Comment

  - New Comment
  - Comment Confirmation

I have setup a demo to show this https://snack.expo.dev/RFG9iFONl

Routing is working for this flow `Home > New Comment > Comment Confirmation > Post`.

I am trying to get the routing working for this flow `Home > Post 1 Home > New Comment > Comment Confirmation > Post` which uses the same page for the final redirect `Comment Confirmation`.

`Comment Confirmation` does the below navigate call for both flows but the second flow ends up at `Post Home` instead of `Post` with `postId=1` as the passed in param. How can i get this routing working for both?

```
navigation.navigate("Post", {
   screen: "Post",
   params: { postId }
});
```

Comment: @AfronmanJ Have you found any solution?

Comment: @AlauddinAhmed unfortunately I havent. I think the only solution would be to rearrange the hierarchy and have the nested component in the root navigation.